# Ruby on rails omniauth-twitter and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, devise

I try to implement the oauth-twitter gem to allow my users to sign-up/sign-in with twitter, the thing is that when the users is redirected after accepting my app on twitter, it redirect him to the sign up page.

Here is my config:

app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
     def twitter
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.twitter.data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end   end

end
```

then my app/models/users.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:twitter]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
  end
end


def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.twitter_data"] && session["devise.twitter_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end


end
```

my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem "font-awesome-rails", "~> 4.0.1.0"
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.0'
gem "zeroclipboard-rails", "~> 0.0.10"
gem "will_paginate", '~> 3.0'
gem 'intercom-rails', '~> 0.2.24'
gem 'magnific-popup-rails'
gem "rake"
gem 'omniauth-twitter'





group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

in config/initializers/devise.rb

I added the:

```
require 'omniauth-twitter'
  config.omniauth :twitter, "APP_ID", "APP_KEY", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter
```

But when my users sign up via the link:

```
 <%= link_to "Sign in with twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
```

and accept my app on twitter they are redirected to the sign up page, and it's not filling anything, I know the email adress can't be retrieve via twitter, but what about the name ? it should fill out the name?

Thanks for pointing what would be wrong

Comment: Does your view code use the @user.name or whatever values you're trying to automatically fill in?

Comment: @JohnPaulAshenfelter I am not sure of what you're asking,but I do have it in app/views/users/show.html.erb where <% provide(:title, @user.name) %> show the user name in the user profile page

Answer (score 0):

Note that the email can now be retrieved from Twitter. For that, you have to go in your Twitter dev account (https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps), select your app and go in the "Permissions" settings. There, you can click on "Edit" and check the box to "Request email address from users".

After that, your omniauth with Twitter should work correctly. That being said, you might want to inform users about the errors they encounter. For that reason, I would add an alert notice inside your `twitter` method in case the authentication fails:

```
  def twitter
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Twitter") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.twitter.data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end   
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

inside your User model's new_with_session(params, session) method, you didn't retrieve data from the data return from twitter, do some assignment there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Can you give me some advices on how I can get some data return from here?

Comment: take a look at the twitter api or just output the session["devise.twitter.data"] value to the rails console and get what you want.

Comment: Thank you - I am not sure how I can do that? can you give me the rails console? thanks

Comment: @zacchj It is the console where you type the command "rails s" to start the rails server. In your code you can use puts to output everything, and the result of puts is display in that console.